# JSP Session.getAttribute() value return null

Tags: jsp, session

I have no idea why my session.getAttribute("user") return not null but attribute value retun null after few minutes, it might due to session time out but why only the attribute value return null but other session still there even session.getAttribute("user") return not null.

This is my web page flow, User Login

LoginServlet

```
User s = new User();
s.retriveuser();
session.setAttribute("balance", s.getBalance());
session.setAttribute("username", s.getUsername());
session.setAttribute("user", s);
```

My Profile

```
        User user = new User();
        if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        } else {
            user = (model.User) session.getAttribute("user");
        }

 <tr>
         <th>Gender:</th>
              <td><%=user.getGender()%></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
         <th>Name:</th>
         <td><%=user.getName()%></td>
 </tr>
```

It can display after the user login everything work fine, after few minutes the gender name ... will display null instead of redirect to login page. And my balance and username session still there.
Before setting else user = (User) session.getAttribute("user"); I was using

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="model.User" scope="session" />
```

Comment: I don't have the same problem. But, my problem is similar. I set the id attribute (id = "name") in a form. I submit this form to a servlet. The servlet takes the id and gets the parameter using request.getParameter("name"). The parameter is set as a session attribute. When i try to access this, attribute finally using a JSP, I get a null. Why ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't readily have access to test this out. But I am guessing the `user` object is not created in the session, hence it does not get set to `null`.

```
if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    user = null;
} else {
    user = (model.User) session.getAttribute("user");
}
```

Should solve your problem.

**Edit** Also, simply printing `user.Gender()` will return `null` in this case, so you're better off printing it straight from the session variable.

Comment: Can you tell me WHY session.getAttribute("someId"); in a JSP could be returning null ? That is, when you get this error, what is the list of causes for this problem ?

Comment: The cause is usually because the session has been invalidated either by logout or by timeout. There could be another reason and that being the `someid` object hasn't been set in session in the first place.

Comment: So, how do i fix this thing ? I tried using getSession(true) and that failed. I guess all my code is fine. Don't know why I am still getting that null. Please also see the comment below. Thanks.

Comment: I set the id attribute (id = "name") in a form. I submit this form to a servlet. The servlet takes the id and gets the parameter using request.getParameter("name"). The parameter is set as a session attribute. When i try to access this attribute finally inside a JSP, I get a null. Why ?

Comment: I am guessing you're just setting the id attribute and not the name attribute. Can't really say much without looking at the code.

To handle the above issue, you need to check if the session is actually available before trying to get attribute. if it is not, redirect the user to a timeout page.

Answer (score 2):

> *I have no idea why my session.getAttribute("user") return not null but attribute value retun null after few minutes*

Ok, so attribute "user" becomes null.

> *it might due to session time out but why only the attribute value return null but other session still there even session.getAttribute("user") return not null.*

Que??  So attribute "user" is not null??

There are only two possibilities for changing session attributes:

1. If your session times out: all attributes are cleared by the container at the same time.
2. If your session does not timeout, and only one of your attributes is cleared: one attribute was cleared by your program.

Extra Note A: from javadoc for `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect`:  After using this method, the response should be considered to be committed and should not be written to.  Your code above violates this.

Extra Note B:

```
   User user = new User();
```

You just populated it with a rubbish new, empty user object.  Avoid that - it's a bug waiting to happen.  Only set variables to useful/valid values.
:)

Answer (score 0):

What have you been using inside the bean code? Are you sure you have made an empty constructor, getters, setters, that the java class implements Serializable?Then, on the jsp page it's better that you use  `<jsp:setProperty name="the_same_you_used_in_bean_id" property="*"/>`. If you want some more info about the bean structire, let me know!