# session().getAttribute is returning null

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I have a servlet which calls a jsp page.
In the servlet I am retrieving the username provided at the login correctly.
But after setting the same in session, when i access the called jsp page, its returning null.

### Servlet Code:

```
public class AdminServlet extends HttpServlet {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4244742541587179390L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userName =  request.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println("UserName: " + userName); // Here it prints the username properly
    request.getSession(true).setAttribute(request.getParameter("name"), userName );
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("upload.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
//  response.sendRedirect("upload.jsp");
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request,response);
}
}
```

JSP Code snippet where I am accessing this:

```
<label class="message">Welcome <%= session.getAttribute("userName") %></label>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone help please

Comment: request.getSession(true).setAttribute(request.getParameter("name"), userName ); ??? I think it should be request.getSession(true).setAttribute("userName", userName );

Comment: What [Stefan Beike](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1640490/stefan-beike) says. Also consider the following idiom: `request.getUserPrincipal().getName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you inverted the two params. It should be like this:

```
   request.getSession(true).setAttribute("userName", userName );
```

Answer (score 1):

you should get session value from the value of

```
request.getParameter("name");
```

or in servlet you need as follow:

request.getSession(true).setAttribute("userName",request.getParameter("name") );

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong:

```
request.getSession(true).setAttribute(request.getParameter("name"), userName );
```

I think it should be

```
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("userName", userName );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick look I think this might be a little similar and might help: [JSP Session.getAttribute() value return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437705/jsp-session-getattribute-value-return-null)